# Minor bug in editor

Tags: bug

In [one of my answers](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/162822/travel-to-a-tower-with-a-gorgeous-view-toward-fuji-mountain/162823#162823), I had a quote, and inadvertently failed to put a blank line afterward. So the white space collapsed, appending the attribution to the last line of the quote.

I clicked ‘edit’ and put my cursor in front of the word ‘from.’  Hit return, and instead of a blank line, the blockquote tag appeared in the edit box.

Comment: Did you accidentally hold Shift while pressing Enter? Because pressing Enter while holding Shift on a line with blockquote formatting will automatically add a new line with blockquote tag.

Comment: I doubt it, but it's possible.  The two keys are adjacent.  Sounds like a feature that would be useful when intended but likely more often unwanted.